# is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, class, partial

I have partial class as follows

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    static string MD5Hash { get; set; }
    static string SHA1Hash { get; set; }
}
```

and two static properties. When I set the static property, I got error in static method.

```
public static void ComputeSHA1Hash(object filePath)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream((string)filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var sha1gen = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            sha1gen.ComputeHash(stream);
            ThisAddIn.SHA1Hash = BitConverter.ToString(sha1gen.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is that? Which error do you get?

Comment: Declare SHA1Hash property as public.

Comment: This question has been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668089/class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668089/class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the `partial` keyword. Rather, you didn't have access modifiers on your class' properties. This means that they're `private` by default. To solve this, simply add `public` to your property declarations.