# Inaccesible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna-4.0

I am triyng to add an animation to my project.Although I add the class referance to another classs , visual studio is giving the following error:

```
inaccesible due to its protection level
```

I define the datatype but nothing has changed.Here is my code block ;

```
  static Dictionary<string, AnimationClip> ProcessAnimations(
       AnimationContentDictionary animations, IList<BoneContent> bones)
    {
        // Build up a table mapping bone names to indices.
        Dictionary<string, int> boneMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < bones.Count; i++)
        {
            string boneName = bones[i].Name;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(boneName))
                boneMap.Add(boneName, i);
        }

        // Convert each animation in turn.
        Dictionary<string, AnimationClip> animationClips;
        animationClips = new Dictionary<string, AnimationClip>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AnimationContent> animation in animations)

        {
            AnimationClip processed = ProcessAnimation(animation.Value, boneMap);

            animationClips.Add(animation.Key, processed);
        }
```

And this part is giving this error :

```
  animationClips = new Dictionary<string, AnimationClip>();
```

The AnimationClip class :

```
class AnimationClip
{
    public AnimationClip(TimeSpan duration, List<Keyframe> keyframes)
    {
        Duration = duration;
        Keyframes = keyframes;
    }
    /// </summary>
    public AnimationClip()
    {
    }

    /// </summary>
    [ContentSerializer]
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a combined list containing all the keyframes for all bones,
    /// sorted by time.
    /// </summary>
    [ContentSerializer]
    public List<Keyframe> Keyframes { get; private set; }
}
```

Anybody can help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us the `AnimationClip` class. This is merely speculation but given that you did not give an explicit accessibility modifier to the `ProcessAnimations` method, you probably didn't for the `AnimationClip` class either. If you do not declare an accessibility modifier, the compiler will assume the most restrictive one which in the case of a class is `internal`. Make the `AnimationClip` class `public`. If you need further help then please update your question to include the complete code listing.

Comment: Can you show the AnimationClip class declaration? My guess is that it is a private class or something.

Comment: I ve edited with AnimationClip class.

Comment: You have not specified the [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173121.aspx) on the `AnimationClip` class. So it defaulted to `private`.

Comment: Thank you @Corak . Now there is no error.

Comment: **Side Note**: To improve readability you could declare like this `var animationClips = new Dictionary<string, AnimationClip>();`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668089/class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
class AnimationClip
```

to

```
public class AnimationClip
```

Making it's member public is a thing but the class itself needs to be public too if you want to access it this way.