# Collections - Lists

Tags: c#, collections, reference, project, solution

Today I need to do an exercice regarding collections.

My Solution have 3 Projects, one is called "Console" the other is called "Entities" and the new project is called "Business".

My Console projects have the Main entry point.
My Entities project have all the classes and parent classes of this exercise.
My new project called Business have a class called Clientadm.

Edit1: This last class have a method that lists the instances of a class called "ClientIndividual" inside Entities.

```
        #region Metodos
        List<ClienteIndividuo> ListarClienteIndividuo = new List<ClienteIndividuo>();
        #endregion
```

The problem is I see a red line in new list saying "Is innacesible due to its protection level".

I have a reference called "Entities" in my Business proyect. 
Im using Entities namespace on my Clientadm class.
My class ClientIndividual is just class, not abstract.

what could it be?

Thanks.

Edit2: Also, intellisense is not working when I want to write any classes of entities into business.

Comment: Are your classes `public`?

Comment: No, just class.

Thank you very much, did not notice it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class is inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668089/class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both the class is `public` as well as any attributes that you want to access are declared `public` as the default in C# is `private`. Example class below.

```
public class FooBar {  
    public List<string> Foo { get; set; }
}
```

[MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is the *access modifier* of your class. Access modifiers are keywords that essentially tell the compiler who can "see" (access) your class (hence the

> Is innacesible due to its protection level

error).

In C#, the access modifiers are `public`, `private`, `protected` and `internal`. In your case, the class should be `public` so that it can be accessed anywhere in the namespace.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

By default class protection level is internal. Internal classes can't be accessed outside the library. Please make it public. You can take a look at [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) in c#.